# Changing the mouse cursor on each and every part of the web page

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#sales-period").on("change", function () {
    $("body").css("cursor", "wait");
});
```

Above is the code that I'm using to change my mouse cursor, when a drop down value is changed, the problem is, the cursor does change to the wait state over the body but when I hover over the links, it still changes back to the pointer. How can I compell it to keep showing the wait state even while hovering the links etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As [Yotam has posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17529215/370103), you could override **every** element's css `cursor` style by doing:

```
$("*").css("cursor", "wait");
```

However, this is very costly as the DOM will have to be changed for every element on the page.

Plus, it will be a nightmare returning all the cursors back to the state they were before they were assigned to wait. If they previously had inline styles then these will have been overridden and you will not be able to return them to the previous state.

---

Therefore I would suggest adding a class to the `body`, and then making all changes in your CSS:

```
$("body").addClass("waiting");

body.waiting,
body.waiting a:hover,
body.waiting *
{
    cursor: wait !important;
}
```

Then to remove the wait state you simply do:

```
$("body").removeClass("waiting");
```

This involves far fewer DOM changes, and fixes your issue with anchor hover state cursors.

Comment: The `!important` declaration should go after the `cursor:wait;`.

Comment: Cheers @Paul. Correction made.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [CSS universal selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/universalselector) `*` to select all elements on the page:

```
$("*").css("cursor", "wait");
```

For better preformance you can target only tags that have different cursors such as links or other tags you changed their cursor by yourself..

To revert back to the regular cursors use:

```
$("*").css('cursor','auto');
```

Comment: And what happens to any cursor(s) that have already been assigned to DOM elements before this code runs? i.e. How would you "remember" their state and return it?

Comment: @LeeTaylor That's why I am waiting for a better answer.

Comment: I guess using a class like @Curt suggested will be the best idea in this case.

Comment: @KamranAhmed - Curt's answer looks to be the one

Comment: @LeeTaylor Yep, I was thinking the same :)

Comment: @YotamOmer - Your revert code will not work where a particular cursor was set explicitly on DOM element(s).

Comment: If you're using the universal selector and want to revert back to the previously assigned selector, just add a new class (e.g. waiting) with css  `cursor: wait !important;`. Then `$('*').addClass('waiting')` and `$('*').removeClass('waiting')` will reset to the previous selection.

Answer (score 1):

You need CSS reset for all `html` elements. You have set cursor for `body` element. But `a` element has default pointer cursor.

Try this `style.css` file

```
body.wait,
body.wait * {
    cursor: wait;
}
```

Jquery code to show/hide wait cursor:

```
$("body").addClass("wait"); // to add wait cursor

$("body").removeClass("wait"); // to remove wait cursor
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
jQuery( "*" ).css("cursor", "wait");
```